# Tabbar icon not able to see

Tags: ios, tabbar

I put this icon onto tabbar, but on the device only a grey rectangle I can see. Should I transform somehow my image to see it?

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you wrote.

Comment: I do not have any code, I have a storyboard a view controller and a `UITabbar` on it, try to add upper image

Comment: I do not understand why I get the down votes, I think this is a reasonable question, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, the actual unselected and selected images are
>   automatically created from the alpha values in the source images. To
>   prevent system coloring, provide images with
>   `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`.

Images have to have 1-color with transparent backgrounds. Unless you assign the images programatically and set the image's `renderingMode` to `AlwaysOriginal`.

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"myImage.png").imageWithRenderingMode(renderingMode: AlwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: And you can set `imageWithRenderingMode` in `Images.xcassets` too.